# How to do EDA on large datasets

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, pandas, bigdata, data-analysis

I have a table in Postgres with ~5million records. When I load the dataset using pandas to perform EDA, I run out of memory.

```
dataframe_chunk = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from table", con = credentials)
```

How do I load and store the table in a format such that I can run all pandas/numpy functions for data analysis?  What is the general approach taken?

Answer (score 1):

You can try sampling the data, chunking, or using spark.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189960/how-to-handle-large-yet-not-big-data-datasets) appears to be a similar post with additional insight into the techniques for reading/writing big datasets.